# how to set current date using jquery ui date picker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I need to set current date using Angular/Jquery UI date picker. I am using below directive to date picker

```js
app.directive('basicpicker', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
      element.datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        setDate: '0',
        onSelect: function(date) {
          scope.$apply(function() {
            ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(date);
          });
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<input type="text" ng-model="mydate" basicpicker/>
```

according to jquery ui date picker documentation , it said 'setDate' can use for it. but i used it in my directive. but not working it.

Comment: Are you looking for [`defaultDate`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-defaultDate) ? `setDate` is a method, not an option.

Comment: i need to load current date.

Comment: use defaultDate : null

Comment: when my page load, current date should be in the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

You could retrieve your datepicker element and call the setDate function on it, as such:

```
$("YOURDATEPICKER").datepicker("setDate", new Date());
```

Comment: i need to do it using angular directive. how i apply 'setDate' to my directive

Comment: In that case have you tried adding 'defaultDate: new Date()' or 'defaultDate: null' to the directive?

Answer (score 0):

var date= $.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', new Date());

you may try this.